The issue of bitsandbytes package supporting CUDA 12.4 version
when running the peft fine-tuning program, execute the following code:
model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)
report errors:
Could not find the bitsandbytes CUDA binary at WindowsPath('D:/Users/1/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/bitsandbytes/libbitsandbytes_cuda124.dll')
The installed version of bitsandbytes was compiled without GPU support. 8-bit optimizers, 8-bit multiplication, and GPU quantization are unavailable.
The latest bitsandbytes package has been installed, version bitsandbytes-0.43.1

I also checked on GitHub, and the latest version supports CUDA 12.4, but
D:/Users/1/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/bitsandbytes/
There is still no libbitsandbytes_cuda124.dll in the directory,
but there are 117 to 123.
Please answer my questions.
I hope this issue can be resolved.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use CMake to generate a visual studio solution and then build this solution to get libbitsandbytes_cuda124.dll
